# Pushing to Heroku fails (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I'm having issues pushing to Heroku I run

```
git push heroku master
```

It starts pushing, then fails with this error

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   NameError: uninitialized constant Devise
   /tmp/build_e47e5acc3405b13038fee9893d25b35a/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here's my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'spring', group: :development
gem 'byebug', group: :development
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0', group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.7'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

It appears Devise is the culprit, would I have to add Devise to " group :production do"? I haven't assigned it to any particular group, but it is in the Gemfile.

Thanks guys.

Edit: I've added "Devise" to :production do, and still the same result.

Comment: When deploying, does it state that Devise was installed during bundle?

Comment: can you post your devise.rb file, please. Also, do not put the devise gem just in production block. it should be in all envs, like rails

Comment: @codyeatworld it does not

Comment: Are you sure that you've committed your `Gemfile` with devise to your repo?

Comment: @ryan-bigg I added --without production, and it seemed to work. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Run bundle update, commit Gemfile and Gemfile.lock, push code, and then deploy to heroku. Also make sure heroku is using your latest commit.

Comment: @MontanaMendy how did you fix this problem? can you explain more with the code you used?